# Find Files having multiple links in shell script

Tags: shell

I want to find the files which have multiple links.
I am using ubuntu 10.10.

```
find -type l
```

It will shows all links to the file but I want to count links for particular file.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about trying to find `hard links` or `soft links`? The former is reasonably easy, the latter means visiting every link, and making an in memory map of where every link points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this command, you will get a sumary of linked files:

```
find . -type l -exec readlink -f {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

or

```
find . -type l -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 readlink -f | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```